# CSS changing fade color of child menu links

Tags: css, menu

http://jsfiddle.net/5DZSy/

I have the main menu links colored and fading the way I want, but the child menu links.. I am trying to make those Black and fade to a different color.. Im a complete newb with css.. and cant figure it out. Ive tried adding and changing classes, and gotten myself lost..

How could I change it so the main links stay like they are, but the child menus have a different color scheme?

The link above to jsfiddle has the html and css..

I appreciate any help and input! I know this is probably simple and something im overlooking, but thats why im here!

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
<li>
    <hr class="menuhr">
<li>
    <a href="#">Link #1</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="blackLink">Child A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Child B</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

css is on the jsfiddle link.. couldnt get it to paste and display right here, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add following styles at bottom:

```
ul#menu li > ul li a {
    color: #000;  /*your submenu link color*/
} 

ul#menu li > ul li a:hover {
    color: #555;   /*your submenu link hover color*/
}
```

Look at here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DZSy/2/)

Comment: Thank you, both of these are right.. Im going to have to get a book, but I think I see now how the logic goes to adjust just those elements.. wish I could mark both right!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/5DZSy/1/

```
#menu li ul li a{color:green}
```